# JDK install manualy in linux

Tags: linux, installation, jdk

I download jdk .bin file for linux .
how to install it that all of the features enable in every where .

Comment: Which distribution do you use ?

Comment: Ubuntu 9.04 is distribution that i use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must set Environment variable:
do something like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/sjb/jdk1.6.0_16
export JRE_HOME=/home/sjb/jdk1.6.0_16
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I am not a big fan of JAVA_HOME and the like. It speaks of global, unscoped data, and that is a bad thing. I prefer to just have symbolic links in /usr/bin and leave it at that (still global data, but less of it because most likely you will still require the symbolic links anyway).

When installing from a .bin these are the steps I take:
1) Execute the .bin file. This creates a directory with the JDK inside
2) Move the directory to a shared system location. I use /usr/java. You may chose /usr/share/java, /opt and so on
3) Create symbolic links in /usr/bin for java. javac and the other executables

Some applications DEMAND a JAVA_HOME (e.g. Tomcat). If this is the case I do a:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/java-1.5; ./runApp
```

Comment: this manual not work

Comment: Which bit did not work?

Comment: JRE_HOME also needed

Answer (score 1):

I unpack it in `/usr/jav`a, and then create a file in `/etc/profile.d` to set the expected environment variables for everyone that logs in.

```
$ chmod +x ~/jdk-6u16-linux-i586.bin
$ cd /usr/java
$ sudo ~/jdk-6u16-linux-i586.bin
$ sudo vi /etc/profile.d/java.sh
  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_16
  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
$ sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/java.sh
```